# ISCSI target service on Centos OS 7 errors

Tags: centos7, iscsi, lun

I have problem with ISCSI Target Utils. Service started normally, but showing errors:

```
systemd[1]: Starting tgtd iSCSI target daemon...
tgtd[3138]: tgtd: iser_ib_init(3436) Failed to initialize RDMA; load kernel modules?
tgtd[3138]: tgtd: work_timer_start(146) use timer_fd based scheduler
tgtd[3138]: tgtd: bs_init(386) use signalfd notification
systemd[1]: Started tgtd iSCSI target daemon.
```

Target defined properly, but no present after command `tgt-admin -s`.
Remove and install scsi-target-utils not resolve problem.
What is wrong ?

Comment: Please provide your target configuration so we can have an idea of what's going on. Also, are you trying o use RDMA via iSER?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue.

I have found that the cause was "default-driver" parameter in my *.conf file in the `/etc/tgt/conf.d` folder.

By default, the default-driver parameter is included in targets.conf so it looks like it conflict with "default-driver" in my file and it should be defined only once.

I have deleted "default-driver" in my file and it resolves the problem.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Neither file includes the `default-driver` line, and the error is still happening. Including it in either file - no change. :(